# How do I repeat an included .tex file multiple times?

Tags: include, latexmk

I would like to repeat a file in a LaTeX document multiple times:

```
\include{probenahme/sample}
\include{probenahme/sample}
\include{probenahme/sample}
\include{probenahme/sample}
\include{probenahme/sample}
```

However, if I compile the main document with `latexmk -pdf main-document.tex`, It will throw the following error:

```
 level-1 auxiliary file: probenahme/sample.aux
Already encountered file probenahme/sample.aux
---line 26 of file probenahme.aux
 : \@input{probenahme/sample.aux
 :                              }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Already encountered file probenahme/sample.aux
---line 27 of file probenahme.aux
 : \@input{probenahme/sample.aux

...
```

- It works fine with a single `\include{probenahme/sample}`
- It works if I run `pdflatex main-document.tex` instead of `latexmk -pdf main-document.tex`
- I don't want to use the `latexmk -f` option because it runs in a continuous integration environment and I want that to catch other errors.

What is the problem and how do I solve it while still using `latexmk`?

Comment: if you don't need anything in any of the `.aux` files, you could try adding `\nofiles` to the preamble.

Comment: Is this really useful to include the same file over and over again? Each time the `.aux` file is written then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not need `\include` functionality here as there is no way to use `\includeonly` to specify just one of the inclusions as they have the same name.
So use `\input` not `\include` then you can input the file as often as you like.